# "with whom" or "whom with"

Tags: prepositions, word-order, formality

I've been looking, but I have not come across this 'whom' related question anywhere. 
Specifically in this circumstance, I feel 'with whom' flows more naturally but I remember someone suggested that 'whom with' is actually the proper order since it is referencing 'the people'

> I am looking to find a friendly environment where I can enjoy my work and the people whom with I work.

Or

> I am looking to find a friendly environment where I can enjoy my work and the people with whom I work.

Answer (score 5):

You could always go with "I am looking to find a friendly environment where I can enjoy my work and the people I work with."  :-)

However, "with whom" is clearly the correct form for your proposed wording.  Whoever suggested "whom with" was smoking dope or something it like.

Comment: Yah I'm glad I asked :) it does seem ridiculous.

Comment: I think the person who suggested "whom with" took inspirations from "wherewith," "wherefore," etc.

Answer (score 3):

Your second example is correct.  I don't believe I've ever seen "whom with".

Answer (score 1):

"with whom" is correct, because your dependent clause is "with whom I work", and prepositions (emphasis on **pre**) should in most cases **introduce** a prepositional phrase, except in some cases where it makes the statement seem awkward.

Comment: Thanks! Excellent answer! I find avoiding ending my sentences with prepositions is a constant tricky battle.

Comment: "Whom I work" is not a clause; you are missing the "with".  [with whom] is the prepositional phrase, and the larger clause is [[with whom] I work].

Comment: Oops, you're right, thanks for pointing that out. I'll update my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

(BrE) Although prescriptivists will lament, in British standard spoken English, I would say neither of these is the norm. Nearly everyone will say:

*I am looking to find a friendly environment where I can enjoy my work and the people I work with.*

Actually *looking to find* also sounds pretty formal to me, and *enjoying people* has certain overtones, so they'd be more likely to say:

*I am looking for a friendly environment where I can enjoy my work and the company of the people I work with.*

Forget the old 'rule' about not ending a sentence with a preposition. Churchill killed that one, if it wasn't dead already. In the UK, *whom* is now used mostly only in written English, and only after a preposition, so  - *with whom*

And this is what virtually all British-published English language courses for foreigners now teach.

You do occasionally hear someone use *whom* in spoken English, but they stick out like a sore thumb. Believe me, *whom* is on the way out.

Answer (score 1):

The "whom with" suggestion might actually refer to the "whom...with" structure, like:

*I am looking to find a friendly environment where I can enjoy my work and the people **whom** I work **with***

Comment: OP already notes that as a possibility.